# dynamic column resizing in Matlab based on excel inputs

Tags: matlab, autoresize, xlsread

I want to read in some data from excel into Matlab say a 3x10 matrix. I need to distinguish whether the some cells are empty or blank in the read data. If empty, delete the row, if zero leave the matrix unchanged.

I am facing two problems with this: Matlab automatically truncates the leading empty cells in the matrix but leaves the empty cells within. Automatically resizing the matrix/array.

Comment: Are you talking about a matrix or a cell array? A Matrix can't have empty elements. Can you give some example data and the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you have the following excel spreadsheet:

[image]

[**`xlsread`**](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html) will read the sheet and fill empty cells with `NaN`:

```
A = xlsread('data.xlsx')

A =

     9     2     1
     3     9     8
     0   NaN     7
     3     4     0
```

Finally you just need to filter out the rows containing `NaN`s:

```
A = A(find(~any(isnan(A),2)),:)

A =

     9     2     1
     3     9     8
     3     4     0
```